# HTML Double Click Selection Oddity

Tags: html, dom, double-click

I didn't post this on DocType because it's not really a `design` thing, the visual representation isn't my problem, the *behaviour* is. I'm sorry if this is misplaced but I don't feel it's a designer issue.

The following DOM:

```
<ul style="overflow: hidden;">
   <li style="float: left;"><strong>SKU:</strong>123123</li>
   <li style="float: left;"><strong>ILC:</strong>asdasdasdasd</li>
</ul>
```

Or

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
   <div style="float: left; width: 49%"><strong>SKU:</strong>123123</div>
   <div style="margin-left: 50%; width: auto;"><strong>ILC:</strong>asdasdasdasd</div>
</div>
```

Or

```
<p>
   <span><strong>SKU:</strong>123123</span>
   <span><strong>ILC:</strong>asdasdasdasd</span>
</p>
```

All present me an odd problem in

- IE 6
- IE 7
- Firefox 3.x
- Chrome

But not in

- IE 8

When you **double click** '123123' after 'SKU:', it selects '123123' AND 'ILC:' from the next dom element.

Take any text on this page (here in SO), double click a word, it only selects *THAT WORD*, even in the middle of a paragraph. These examples have dom elements closing them, anyone know why this is happening.

My fellow employees use the 'double click' mechanism to select the relevant product ID's to do their job, and this dosen't make sense to me what soever.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem. If you put a space before the closing tag of your li that should fix it.

```
<ul style="overflow: hidden;">
    <li style="float: left;"><strong>SKU:</strong>123123 </li>
    <li style="float: left;"><strong>ILC:</strong>asdasdasdasd </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Solved my problem. But it's really strange.

Answer (score 4):

If you put a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;` or `\u00A0`) or just a empty space (`" "`) between each `span`, it will separate the words and prevent the double-click selection from spilling into adjacent spans.

If you don't want to see a visible space, use a zero-width space (`&ZeroWidthSpace;` or `\u200B`).​​​

Comment: Only &nbsp; after the first span worked. Amazingly even changing spans to div - did not work...

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that if you include a space or a non-breaking space `&nbsp` between your two elements, you will find that you can double-click, and select only one but not both elements, as the browser will no longer see the two elements as a single word.

Comment: I did actually. `&nbsp;`, i tried 10 of them when i was about to pull my hair out. It didn't work.

Comment: I pasted all three of your variants into a new webpage, and opened it in IE7.  I was unable to reproduce the problem on any of the variants.

Comment: If it helps it's in an absolute-positioned, z-index 5 overlay. :/