# How can I control how much text a double-click selects?

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to select a "code" by double-clicking it. But when I do so, the whole definition is selected.

```css
dt {
  float: left;
  clear: left; 
}
dd {
  float: left;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Code</dt>
  <dd>123456</dd>
  <dt>Code</dt>
  <dd>abcdef</dd>
</dl>
```

What can I do so that a double-click will select the contents of the `dd` only?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198831/text-selection-on-double-click-in-html-with-a-float

Comment: Also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876424/html-double-click-selection-oddity

Comment: Double clicking already selects only the dd contents. Voting to close as no repro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a Chrome issue so to solve it you will need to add space before you close the html tag. So you have to do it like this.

```
<dl>
  <dt> Code </dt>
  <dd> 123456 </dd>
  <dt> Code </dt>
  <dd> abcdef </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: No i dont but it happened to me before and i remember that i read something that it was chrome issue but now i see it happens in all browsers. Anyway the solution i gave solves it.

Comment: Oh, I upvoted as it works and it's lightweight but I'd hoped for a reason...ah well.

Comment: What i read also was the float causing it if it helps you. But i dont know why in details.

Comment: I like this because it was the easiest and fastest to implement in our case.

Comment: Thank you and im glad that it solved your problem :)

Comment: @E.Agolli It's not a bug, when you double click, the un-break content at your cusor will be selected. At an space is a trix :) anyway, it's usefull.

Comment: Unfortunately this trick doesn't seem to work any more (Chrome 118). Using a non-breaking space `&nbsp;` seems to work but it's visible and adds the risk of the user selecting it too so it's a recipie for disaster. I'll continue searching for a way to improve this.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [table](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) instead of a styled description list that looks like a table

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Code</td>
    <td>123456</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Code</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>  
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A definition list is a semantically appropriate structure in many cases—notably in the case of 1:1 title/definitions. Tables are for tabular data, so this “solution” is not really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You float left all your element, I thinks it make confusing for double click action known what element is selected. Remove "float:left" attribute on your `<dd>` element. [float and clear](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

```css
dt {
  float: left;
  clear: left; 
  margin-right: 10px;
}
dd {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Code</dt>
  <dd>123456</dd>
  <dt>Code</dt>
  <dd>abcdef</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: This could be also a solution since floating is causing it.

Comment: In general, I'm always in favor of less floating. But when I remove the `float` from the `dd`, it breaks our layout :(

Comment: Your layout is break because you set special font for your `<dd>` element. You must spend a lot of time to make up them :)

Answer (score 2):

After encoutering the same problem on **Chrome 118** I noticed the space hack doesn't work any more  so I looked for other options and ended up using `user-select: all`:

```css
dl {
  user-select: none;
}
dd {
  user-select: all;
}
```

Setting this on each `dd` element makes sure no matter where you click on how many clicks, it always select the whole `dd` value (and nothing else). The `user-select: none` on the top element is not mandatory, but I found the behavior weird without it because if you start selecting outside and then go inside a `dd` element, it tries to include it all and cause some visual flickering (alternating between selection up to cursor and up to the end of the `dd`).

It works well for my use-case which is to make it easier for people to select the dd value entirely for copying.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

Answer (score -1):

Don't need to modify the html. You can use css:

```css
dl dd::before { content: '.'; display: block; height: 0; width: 0; visibility: hidden; }
dl dd::after { content: '.'; display: block; height: 0; width: 0; visibility: hidden; }
dl dt::before { content: '.'; display: block; height: 0; width: 0; visibility: hidden; }
dl dt::after { content: '.'; display: block; height: 0; width: 0; visibility: hidden; }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).