# Bootstrap: Why does double click select in one span also select text in another span?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, double-click

With the below example, double click select on text "Goodbye" selects the text "world" in the sibling span. Why does this happen and how can it be prevented?

Markup:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <span class="col-xs-6">Hello world</span>
    <span class="col-xs-6">Goodbye world</span>
</div>
```

Example:

[image]

Live example:

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dZl7aysOaVDerrSRZLfW?p=preview)

Edit: without Bootstrap classes the behaviour is as expected, the text "world" is not selected - [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/G60Q8s6y1GBOAPLYFkfA?p=preview).

Comment: This isn't an answer per-se, but have you tried using `<div>` instead of `<span>`?

Comment: @MTCoster Yes. Same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Chrome's devtools to disable the CSS properties set by Bootstrap one by one suggests the issue lies with this part:

```
.col-xs-6 {
    float: left;
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems as though the `float` property is fundamental to Bootstrap's layout.

The issue of `float` causing selection oddities has previously been mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876424/html-double-click-selection-oddity), and the solution posted there (adding a space to the end of the first span) works in your example.

Comment: Only &nbsp; after the first span worked. Amazingly even changing spans to div - did not work...